# Error defining geocoder variable while using Google Maps API and Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, parse-platform

I am attempting to use Parse Cloud Code to geocode an address using the Google Maps API v3. Following the suggested code from Google I am using the following:

```
 Parse.Cloud.afterSave ('IncidentDetails', function(request, status) {

                   var address = request.object.get("address1");
                   var geocoder;

                   function initialize () {

                   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                   codeAddress (address);

                   }

                   function codeAddress () {

                   geocoder.geocode( { 'address':address}, function (results, status) {

                                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                                        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                                        var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
                                        request.object.set("lat", lat);
                                        request.object.set("lng", lng);

                                    } else {

                                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reasons: ' + status);
                                    }
                                    });
                   }

                   initialize ();

                   });
```

The code runs fine after a PFObject is saved, but fails on

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder ();
```

with the error: ReferenceError: google is not defined

I see in HTML where a source is defined and api key set, but I don't see the same for pure java script examples.

Any help on getting the geocoder variable initialized properly would be appreciated.

Comment: You aren't including google API script (or you are trying to use the google.maps objects before the script it is loaded).

Comment: Right... do you have reference to the appropriate script to load the API?  I can find reference for how/where that is done for html, but not plain javascript.  The Google sample code for html+javascript includes a source definition, the plain javascript sample does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google.maps.Geocoder is a javascript meant to work in browser, to use geocode, Make use of Parse.Cloud.httpRequest as below, (You need to have Geocoding API enabled in goolge API console)

`Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                method: "POST",
                url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
                params: {
                    address : address,
                    key:YourKey
                },
                success: function(httpResponse) {
                    var response=httpResponse.data;
                    if(response.status == "OK"){
                        var langLat=response.results[0].geometry.location;
                        console.log(langLat);
                     }
                },
                error: function(httpResponse) {
                    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                }
            });`